# Javascript file not working after ajax call

Tags: ajax

I am using a pagination script. I got it from a template. It has search option plus show items  like 5,10,15,20 and and and prev button. Script is working nicely but when i use ajax and refresh that table part using

```
$(#tablerefresh).html(data)
```

then just a table is show with no search options, no next previous options nothing just all rows show.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='../../js/plugins/Table/Table.js'></script>
```

thats the script file. I placed this inside the calling php page but nothings work. I will post the code if you want to see the script code.any suggestions?

**In sucess function else part runs when updating occurs:**

```
            else
            {
                // Dropdown start option.
                $('select').val(0);

                // Clear fields data. (text).
                $('form :input[type=text]').attr('value','');

                // Password error hide.
                $('#userpassword').css("border-color", "#918C8C");
                $('#userconfirm').css("border-color", "#918C8C");
                $('#usershowdiv').hide();

                // Username - Space error show.
                $('#userspace').css("border-color", "#918C8C");
                $('#usershowdiv3').hide();

                // Username - User already exists error show.
                $('#userexists').css("border-color", "#918C8C");
                $('#usershowdiv4').hide();

                // Show ok image.
                $('#okicon2').show();

                // Hide ok image.
                $('#okicon2').delay(8000).fadeOut();

                // Show success message.
                $('#usersuccess').show();

                // Show success message hide after some time.
                $('#usersuccess').delay(8000).fadeOut();

                // Hide x image.
                $('#crossicon2').hide();

                // Again Display Table after refresh.
                $('#refreshuserlist').html(data);
            }
```

**js:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

    // dataTable    

        if($(".fTable").length > 0)
            $(".fTable").dataTable({bSort: true, 
                                    "iDisplayLength": 5, "aLengthMenu": [5,10,25,50,100], // can be removed for basic 10 items per page
                                    "aoColumnDefs": [{"bSortable": false,
                                                     "aTargets": [ -1 , 0]}]});

    // eif dataTable
});
</script>
```

**how i use that:**

```
<table class="table fTable lcnp" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pager and search are dynamically added to page, then in ajax `success` re-call these functions to apply to new elements, that was replaced in your page:

```
function createSearchField(){
     $('body').append('<div class="search"></div>');
}
```

In ajax:

$.ajax({
       url: 'example.com',
       success: function(){ createSearchField(); //Call once more. }
   })

Comment: can you give an example. should i use the whole script inside ajax success? its too much code

Comment: i updated my else part which is inside the success ajax,

Comment: will you chk this js i pasted in this link http://jsfiddle.net/ryXpD/3/ i tried to call `function(X,l,n);` but it didn't worked.

Comment: @user3400389 If using plugin, look for some update function for it or just reinitialize that plugin.

Comment: reinitialize means copy and paste it in the code file?

Comment: @user3400389 if you call you plugin: `$('.div').datepicker();` and that `.div` is changed dynamically, so in ajax: `success: function(){ $('.div').datepicker();}`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ryXpD/5/ will you see this file. i think this is the file which is the main.

Comment: @user3400389 How you call code from Table.js to make your table with search option and pager size?

Comment: @user3400389 so finally you told, that you are using dataTables plugin. Next time start from that. $.ajax({success: function(){$(".fTable").dataTable();}})

Comment: Hey did it, thankyouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu soooo much for the help. you really helped me. i didn't about pluging usage. but thanks to you i finally now know how to use them.